# Multilingual Website Code Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual, globalization, global-asax

I have a website that has been working fine until I had to delete some incorrect resource files. However this may not be the reason for it not working. Basically, like most multi-language websites the user can change the language by clicking flags:

```
    protected void imbEnglish_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SetCultureStoreCookie("en-GB");
}
protected void imbFrench_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SetCultureStoreCookie("fr-FR");
}
protected void imbGerman_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SetCultureStoreCookie("de-DE");
}
protected void imbSpanish_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SetCultureStoreCookie("es-ES");
}
protected void imbItalian_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SetCultureStoreCookie("it-IT");
}
protected void imbPolish_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SetCultureStoreCookie("fr-FR");
}

protected void SetCultureStoreCookie(string culture)
{
    //Sets the cookie that is to be used by Global.asax
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
    cookie.Value = culture;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    //Set the culture and reload the page for immediate effect. 
    //Future effects are handled by Global.asax

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

    //Response.Redirect(Request.Path);
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
}
```

As it says in the comments, subsequent setting of the culture is handling in the Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CultureInfo"];

    if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    }
}
```

All of the pages, including the master page have English (default) resource files and I have started to create the French ones:

[image: Resource Files]

However, when you click the French flag nothing happens. I've stepped through the code and the cookie is being set and the Thread.CultureInfo line is run.

Any ideas about where else to check?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you edit .csproj with 'supported culture' ? 
Right click on your project, Unload Project, Right click, Edit .csproj, and add :     <SupportedCultures>en,fr</SupportedCultures>

Comment: Hi Joffrey, it's not a project in Visual Studio, it's a simple website, however as I said in the intro the translation used to work, without the .csproj file being present.

Comment: Ok, in my projects (SL/WPF/Win8), I need to add SupportedCultures in the .csproj to have globalization.

Comment: Hi Joffrey, I appreciate what you are saying but it has never has .csproj and it used to work. Also there isn't the option add a .csproj file in the website.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the way it works. Obviously the MasterPage class does not have a method called InitializeCulture, using a couple of tips I saw on other posts I created a BaseClass page:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

/// 
/// Summary description for Translations
/// 
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CultureInfo"];

    if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
    {
        //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
        //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cookie.Value);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
    }

    base.InitializeCulture();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeCulture();
}
```

}

Then changed each page to inherit from the BaseClass page:

```
public partial class AboutUs : BasePage
```

{

}

That solved the problem.